# My aws ec2 micro instance is running out of memory, how can I scale it up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an aws ec2 micro instance that is used for a fairly memory intensive ruby script. (~2GB RAM required).

Obviously, I'm finding the free-tier ec2 instance inadequate for running this script.

I'd like to scale the memory up on this instance without having to start over completely.

How can I add memory to the instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it. You can't scale up memory alone, you have to completely change instance types. The whole process takes about 5 minutes.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html